# Creating a Dart List from a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, dart

I am trying to learn client-side Dart, coming from a server-side Java EE world, and I am having trouble converting an array from an existing JavaScript library into a Dart List.

I am trying to learn by building on the Javascript Interop example that [uses Google Maps](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop/blob/master/example/google-maps/directions.dart). In Google's [Maps API's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsLeg), the `DirectionsLeg` object's `step` property returns.

> array of DirectionsSteps, each of which contains information about the individual steps in this leg

How can I convert this `var` into a Dart List? I have tried the following:

```
final List<maps.DirectionsStep> steps = List.from(directionsLeg.steps);
```

But Dart Editor tells me `cannot resolve method 'from' in class 'List'`. My imports are:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible or must I just accept using a `var`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in way in [js-interop](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop) for now to use Dart `List` when a js `Array` is returned.

`directionsLeg.steps` returns a `js.Proxy` which handles like js `Array`. You can iterate on it like this :

```dart
final steps = directionsLeg.steps;
for (var i = 0; i < steps.length ; i++) {
  final step = steps[i];
  // do the job with step
}
```

If you really want to use a Dart `List` you can convert the `js.Proxy` of js `Array` to a Dart `List` with something like :

```dart
List<js.Proxy> convertToList(js.Proxy arrayProxy){
  final result = new List<js.Proxy>();
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayProxy.length ; i++) {
    result.add(arrayProxy[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

About your code :

- You can't define `List<maps.DirectionsStep>` : `maps.DirectionsStep` is not a type, it's a `js.Proxy` on js `google.maps.DirectionsStep` (moreover it don't really exist - only a container js object `{}`).
- `List.from(...)` : here, you try to call a static method named `from` on Dart `List` object. That why you get your error. [`List.from`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/List.html#List.from) is actually a factory [named constructor](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#constructors) and has to be used with the `new` keyword ( `new List.from(otherIterable)` ).

Comment: Thanks for the comments on the code - I'm really enjoying the language, but the subtle differences with Java trip me up a lot, me treating the named constructor like a static method being a perfect example.